# Combine two arrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I am working on a project of classification of emotions using audio and text. I passed the audio and text to 1D CNN and got the following output arrays:

```
audio_features_shape = (396, 63, 64)
text_features_shape = (52, 1, 64)
```

Now I want to stack these two different dimensions arrays into one so I can pass one array to LSTM. I want the shape as:

```
expected_array_shape = (448, 64, 128)
```

I tried the following methods but no one is giving the output I want.

```
x = np.column_stack((audio_features, text_features))
x = np.concatenate((audio_features,text_features), axis=2)
x = np.append(audio_features, text_features)
x = np.transpose([np.tile(audio_features, len(text_features)), np.repeat(text_features, len(audio_features))])
x = np.array([np.append(text_features,x) for x in audio_features])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a minimal non-ambiguous example (actual arrays, not only the shape) and the expected output?

Comment: Actual arrays are so long, I am unable to print them here.

Comment: thus the *minimal* ;) an example with <10 items per dimension is sufficient

Comment: Sure, let me update my question.

Comment: For example `a = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4); b = np.arange(1 * 1 *5).reshape(1,1,5)`. What is your expected output?

Comment: To me it seems, that you would have a lot of zero's then in your final array. Consider element [0,0,123] of your final array. Or am I mistaken? So for me, it is not so clear where the elements are put in the final array.

Comment: @QuangHoang according to your example I want the expected shape as (3, 4, 9). I am really sorry guys I am new to python and things seem to be complicated to me.

Comment: Your expected array is too big. It would suffice to pad the first axis of the text features to (**396**, 1, 64) and then stack it with the audio features for a final shape of (396, **64**, 64).

Comment: @MUmer yes, but what does that `(3,4,9)` look like? E.g. What are the entries?

Comment: @MUmer the question is less about your desired shape and more about how you fill in the array to fit that shape.

Comment: With 3 dimensions, just think of attaching boxes of different sizes to each other, such that the final shape is a box itself.

Answer (score 3):

How are the values of the 2 arrays supposed to be distributed in the result?

```
audio_features_shape = (396, 63, 64)
text_features_shape = (52, 1, 64)
```

`text_features` should be "expanded" to (52,63,64), either by repeating values 63 times on the middle axis, or putting this array into a target array of 0s.  In either case it will be 63 times larger.

Once the arrays match on all but the first dimension they can be concatenated.

**But the real question is, what makes sense in the LSTM use?**

Comment: I am confused about it. I am new to python so I don't know much. Can you please guide me on how I can fuse two features set and then pass them to a model?

Comment: I outlined how.  I could add some working code, but first I want you to clarify what the model expects.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're suggesting a final output of shape 448x63x64, which is bigger than 396x64x64.

Comment: I was thinking of concatenating the (396,63,64) to a new (52,63,64) to make (448,64,64).  That's not as big as the (448, 64, 128) in the question.  I don't think the OP knows what he needs.  @Reti43

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want and whether you are only interested in using Tensorflow, you could give the following a try:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

audio_features = tf.random.normal((396, 63, 64))
text_features = tf.random.normal((52, 1, 64))

text_features = tf.repeat(text_features, repeats=(audio_features.shape[1]-text_features.shape[1]) + 1, axis=1) 
repeat_features = tf.concat([audio_features, text_features], axis=0)
text_features = tf.random.normal((52, 1, 64))

paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, audio_features.shape[1]-text_features.shape[1]], [0, 0]])
pad_features = tf.concat([audio_features, tf.pad(text_features, paddings, "CONSTANT")], axis=0)

print('Using tf.repeat --> ', audio_features.shape, text_features.shape, repeat_features.shape)
print('Using tf.pad --> ', audio_features.shape, text_features.shape, pad_features.shape)
```

```
Using tf.repeat -->  (396, 63, 64) (52, 1, 64) (448, 63, 64)
Using tf.pad -->  (396, 63, 64) (52, 1, 64) (448, 63, 64)
```